# rejected edit - "edit deviates from the original intent of the post"

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Let's talk about my [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19752606).

It was made in regard to the [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50372685/revisions) made by OP. He asked a question got an answer which not fully solved his problems. Therefore he edited the question by fixing the mistake that was written in the answer.

This makes the answer useless, I told him that he may put the question back into its original form because of this. He tried but deleted the line with the problem all together, so now it seemed that he abandoned the question and I made an edit to fix what I think is a problem. And made it (hopefully) clear in the comments that this is just a fix to a previous edit

But the edit was rejected.

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

To my mind this IS the original intent.

Was my behavior correct? Or what would be the correct approach here.

Comment: You could have rolled back ops edit instead of suggesting a new one. Then it would be clearer what you try to achieve.

Comment: I don't see a fundamental problem with the edit or the summary, but your edit may have been more likely to be approved had you started the summary with something like "Reverted/rolled-back OP's code change, which invalidates...". (1) Put the important part at the start of the comment and (2) use "revert" or "roll-back", because that's a short basic description of your edit.

Comment: @BDL you can only rollback at 2k. Anyway... I reckon it's a decent edit and have retroactively approved it.

Comment: Next time flag it for mod attention. That's how we handle question edits that invalidate answers. BTW you made a good attempt on that answer.

Answer (score 18):

Your edit was correct in this specific case, because OP's edit makes the answer redundant and meaningless.

If OP still have problems, he can ask a new question, or edit the current question if it doesn't totally diverse from the original one.

Your edit was rejected because reviewers didn't pay enough attention to the question, and I bet they didn't read your edit summary (which was very helpful).

Comment: To be honest I'd also reject this suggested edit. Reading the first few words of the edit summary: "OP changed the question in regard to the solution in the answer" makes no sense to me. If you stated something like: "roll-back because the OP invalidated the answer by an edit." I'd approve, as it is clear, and short.